# Is there a keyboard shortcut to shutdown and reboot the computer?

Tags: 64-bit, shortcut-keys, 13.10

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit and I would like to have a short cut that will restart the computer and one that will shutdown. I know how to make shortcuts in the keyboard settings, but I don't know the command. Thanks